# Client Website always return Null Json String

Tags: javascript, c#, json, wcf

I've gotten to a point now where I can receive responses from a client website I've made (for internal use in the company I work at) on my WCF Webservice. But whenever I get a response it's always null.

I've look around for various solutions and none of them seems to fix this issue. I have the following:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "/AddNewActivity")]
String AddNewActivity(String jsonObject);
```

And implemented:

```
public String AddNewActivity(String jsonObject)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Success");
}
```

Just to test that it works. I set a breakpoint at the above function to read the jsonObject string and see what it looks like. When I read it though, it's null. Always null.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function OnModalCreateNewActivityBtnClick() {
    var modal = $('#new-activity-modal-body');
    var activityMap = {
        status: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-status-dropdown').val(),
        name: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-name-field').val(),
        responsible: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-responsible-field').val(),
        department: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-department-dropdown').val(),
        startTime: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-datepicker-start').val(),
        endTime: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-datepicker-end').val(),
        description: modal.find('#editor').cleanHtml(),
        axAccounts: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-ax-account-numbers-field').val()
    };
    var jsonObject = '{ "String": ' + JSON.stringify(activityMap) + '}';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:52535/PUendeligService.svc/AddNewActivity',
        data: jsonObject,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert("Success: " + data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone have any idea why it returns null?

**UPDATE**

I used Fiddler and the information that leaves the website to the web service is correct. It's a JSON String that Fiddler can read. But the web service still receives a null object.

Comment: What happens when you remove `dataType: 'json'`? I have a feeling it's trying to deserialize the request into an object which is contrary to the method accepting a string.

Comment: try  var jsonObject = '{ "jsonObject : ' + JSON.stringify(activityMap) + '}'; since you are using BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest , you paremeter name should match. You should use WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare and there will be no need to use above line.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed them up. If you change `contentType: 'text/plain'` and leave `dataType` as it is.

Comment: @rob I tried what you suggested and it gave me a 400 Bad Request. Also about the WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare I also get Bad Requests no matter what I send when using that type.

Comment: @rob If I try and remove dataType: json it still returns null

Comment: @AnupamSingh Doing that I get a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: try var jsonObj = jsonObject: { activityMap }, then pass JSON.stringify(jsonObj) to post

Comment: @AnupamSingh this gives me an `Unexpected token :` syntax error.

Comment: sorry, use var jsonObj = { jsonObject:  activityMap } instead

Comment: @AnupamSingh I still get a bad request.

Comment: then there might be issue with data(jsonObj), try to inspect this object.

Comment: It appears you know the object before hand so instead of sending var jsonObject = '{ "String": ' + JSON.stringify(activityMap) + '}';  send JSON.stringify(activityMap) and on the receiving side create a model with the exact same properties.  I would write it as an answer to illustrate what I mean if you like.

Comment: @AlexNolasco I'll try that out.

Comment: @AlexNolasco That didn't work. Still get null back.

Comment: WCF and javascript's page are in the same domain url ?

Comment: @Max Yes they are both in the same domain.

Comment: Can you post the PUendeligService.svc markup and the web.config ?

Comment: Have you tried to pass a simple string like 'HelloWord' and see if jsonObject is still null ?

Comment: @Max Yes. It does not matter what I send it keeps being Null in the Web Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify your sample a bit and start with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnModalCreateNewActivityBtnClick() {

        var data = {
            Status: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-status-dropdown').val(),
            Name: modal.find('#new-activity-modal-name-field').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Service.svc/AddNewActivity',
            data: JSON.stringify(data), 
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(data.Status + ' == ' + msg.Status);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('failed with ' + e.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Your activity class

```
   [DataContract]
    public class Activity
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String Status
        {
            get; set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public String Name
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

Implementation

```
[WebInvoke(Method ="POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "AddNewActivity/")]
public Activity AddNewActivity(Activity activity)
{
  // your stuff
  return activity;
}
```

Lastly, since you didn't show your configuration let's assume the following

```
     <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PUendelig.Service"  behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PUendelig.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I put this together in github for you to download. Please feel free to adjust as need be and help others in the process
[https://github.com/alexnolasco/SO35094908](https://github.com/AlexNolasco/SO35094908)

Comment: Alright I will give it a look once I get back to work on Monday. It looks like it could work given that my initial setup is probably out of whack.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be here:

```
var jsonObject = '{ "String": ' + JSON.stringify(activityMap) + '}';
```

Remove that line, as you do not need it and change your AJAX call to the following:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:52535/PUendeligService.svc/AddNewActivity',
        data: {jsonObject: JSON.stringify(activityMap) },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert("Success: " + data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that your service expects "jsonObject" variable, but you are sending "String". Hope this helps.

Comment: Still get a Bad Request :/

Comment: @Vipar Are you able to post a request to a server from some third party tool (e.g. Chrome extension DHC or Fiddler)?

Comment: i don't think json.stringify gives a propery escaped json string all your " need to be replaced with \"

Comment: @Vipar can you capture request, you're sending from client, and post it here? This would significantly help with troubleshooting...

Answer (score 1):

Change the content type from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I'm not sure how you are using it right now but if your prepare data like this var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(activityMap); and put content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded it should work. You don't need to add curly braces manually

Comment: I have this C# part: `[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "/AddNewActivity")]
        String AddNewActivity(String jsonObject);` Not sure if that tells you anything.

Comment: I changed it to doing JSON.stringify(activityMap) and changed the content type but I still get 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Hm.. I don't have any ideas except maybe you can try to update your UriTemplate to this UriTemplate = "/AddNewActivity?jsonObject={jsonObject}" and try with your original js implementation. If that doesn't help than open a Postman and test your service manually..